# Suppress prolog from XML during marshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, mule

I am using Mule XML module `jaxb-object-to-xml-transformer` to convert my object to XML. Then this XML is embedded into another XML using templates.

But the issue here is the object to XML transformer is giving an XML output with prolog:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I need an XML without this. So that it can be embedded into another template without issues.

```
    <flow name="main.flow">
    ....
    ....
    <mule-xml:jaxb-object-to-xml-transformer name="obj2xml" jaxbContext-ref="myJaxbContext"  returnClass="java.lang.String" />
    <custom-transformer ..... >
    ....
    ....
</flow>
```

In plain JAXB there is a way to do this. But in Mule XML module I couldn't find any property to do this. Please advise if there is any property to achieve this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation indicates that you can intercept JAXB transforms (see:  http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JAXB+Bindings).  The following example is taken from that documentation.

```
@Transformer(sourceTypes = {String.class, InputStream.class})
public Person toPerson(Document doc, JAXBContext context) throws JAXBException
{
    return (Person) context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(doc);
}
```

Assuming there is a corresponding thing you can do for marshalling you would be able to set the necessary JAXB property.

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could see that this is a custom transformer. I am looking for some kind or attribute(property) in the current mule transformers that can do this.